# C Programming - Free Method Giving me an Invalid next Size (fast) Error

Tags: c, free, valgrind, getline

I am having a Problem freeing a character pointer which is being allocated by `getLine` function.

The Purpose of the application is to read the /proc/net/dev File and display Information about the Interface passed by the User.

Whenever the free Method executes I am having an Invalid next Size (fast) Error.

I copied the code off a Magazine, but as the Article author said, it should work as is.

The function giving me problems is this

```
int ParseDevFile(const char * Interface, ull *bRx, ull *pRx, ull *bTx, ull *pTx)
{
FILE *FilePointer = NULL;

char *ReadLine = NULL;

unsigned int Length = 0;

FilePointer = fopen("/proc/net/dev", "r");

if (FilePointer == NULL)
{
    perror("Error");
    return -1;
}

while (getline(&ReadLine, &Length, FilePointer) != -1 )
{
    if (strstr(ReadLine, Interface) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(strstr(ReadLine, ":") + 1, "%llu%llu%*u%*u%*u%*u%*u%*u%llu%llu", bRx, bRx, bTx, pTx);
    }
}

free(ReadLine);

fclose(FilePointer);

return 0;
}
```

I am new to the C Language, But if I Read the getline Man Page Correctly it increases the Buffer Size of ReadLine according to the Size of the Line.

Also the Application works Fine when run under valgrind ( apart from some Invalid Writes at the Beginning of the Application).

Below is the Valgrind Error. Note that after These Errors, the Application proceeds in running Normally.

```
==31361== Command: ./ifstat wlan0
==31361== 
==31361== Invalid write of size 8
==31361==    at 0x4EC63FA: __GI_memcpy (memcpy.S:125)
==31361==    by 0x4EA40BF: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:116)
==31361==    by 0x4008FE: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==  Address 0x51fc333 is 115 bytes inside a block of size 120 alloc'd
==31361==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31361==    by 0x4EA404D: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:67)
==31361==    by 0x4008FE: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361== 
==31361== Invalid write of size 1
==31361==    at 0x4EA41B4: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:123)
==31361==    by 0x4008FE: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==  Address 0x51fc33b is 3 bytes after a block of size 120 alloc'd
==31361==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31361==    by 0x4EA404D: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:67)
==31361==    by 0x4008FE: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361== 
==31361== Invalid read of size 1
==31361==    at 0x4C302E4: strstr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31361==    by 0x40089F: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==  Address 0x51fc338 is 0 bytes after a block of size 120 alloc'd
==31361==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31361==    by 0x4EA404D: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:67)
==31361==    by 0x4008FE: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361== 
==31361== Invalid read of size 1
==31361==    at 0x4C2FF14: __GI___rawmemchr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31361==    by 0x4EB237F: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:44)
==31361==    by 0x4E9306F: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:41)
==31361==    by 0x4E93006: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:32)
==31361==    by 0x4008E4: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==  Address 0x51fc338 is 0 bytes after a block of size 120 alloc'd
==31361==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31361==    by 0x4EA404D: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:67)
==31361==    by 0x4008FE: ParseDevFile (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400996: DumpInterfaceUsage (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
==31361==    by 0x400B4F: main (in /home/andrew/C Programming/Magazine Tutorials/ifstat)
```

Thank You,
Andrew Borg

Comment: memory not allocated from `ReadLine`, `Length` is garbage.

Comment: What Do you Mean? I copied this From a Magazine, and I taught that Length was Zero for the getline Method to Extend the Buffer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan [`man 3 getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)  - if you look closely: it will allocate memory for you. There's a reason a pointer-to-pointer is passed, and not simply a pointer to the first element of some buffer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Okh! its nice...thanks for information.

Comment: Hi,
I managed to fix the Problem. The solution was to change the 
`unsigned int Length = 0;` to `size_t Length = 0;`

Nonetheless Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I Managed to fix the Problem by changing the Unsigned Integer Length Variable to type size_t.

```
unsigned int Length = 0;
```

to

```
size_t Length = 0;
```